# CLLocationManager initializing, releasing, initializing and then releasing causes crash?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have a use case where the application will automatically attempt to retrieve a location, the user can deny the permission, then the user can trigger the app to look for the location again (this time allowing it), but then the app will crash. Here's the basic code and use case steps, below, what am I doing wrong?

```
@interface AppViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{  
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager; 

//... method declaration

@end

@implementation AppViewController
@synthesize locationManager; 

-(void)MethodThatAutomaticallyGetsLocation{ 
     [self FindLocation]; 
}
-(IBAction)UserTriggerToGetLocation{ 
     [self FindLocation]; 
} 

-(void)FindLocation{ 
     locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
     locationManager.delegate = self; 
     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
} 
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

      // ... do some stuff
      // ... save location info to core data object

      [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; 
      locationManager.delegate = nil; 
      [locationManager release]; 

}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{ 

      // ... conditionally display error message 
      //     based on type and app state

      [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; 
      locationManager.delegate = nil; 
      [locationManager release]; 
} 

- (void)dealloc {
     // locationManager not released here, its released above
}
@end
```

1. App loads view, messages `MethodThatAutomaticallyGetsLocation`
2. `FindLocation` is called to setup `locationManager`
3. Phone asks permission to share location
4. User denies permission
5. `locationManager:didFailWithError` is called, releases `locationManager`
6. User interacts with UI, triggers `(IBAction) UserTriggerToGetLocation` which calls `FindLocation`
7. Phone asks permission again, this time user allows it
8. `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` does its thing

Then the app crashes inside `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` when `[locationManager release]` is called. Specifically I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` which would imply `locationManager` is released already? but where?

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guh, nevermind. I think I *am* doing something wrong with releasing before `dealloc` but I also realize I don't need to release before then. By simply stopping the locationManager in its response handlers, I can then restart it for step 6 by changing `UserTriggerToGetLocation` to call  `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` NOT `FindLocation` again.